# navigate backbone has no method 'navigate'

Tags: backbone.js, routes, router

i would like to use Routes with navigate but i have an error.

```
(function(){

window.App = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Routers: {}
};

App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "/case-projet/:projet": "caseProjet"
    },
    showPage: function(page){
        //hide all pages
        this.hidePages();
        //show passed page by selector
        $(page).show();
    },
    caseProjet: function (e) {
        this.showPage('div#partech-introduction');
    }

});

new App.Router;
Backbone.history.start();

App.Views.Incentive = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#projet-page"),
    caseStudyContainer: $("#projet-page"),
    caseStudyElem: $('section[data-projet-page="Incentive"]'),
    initialize: function () {
        $("#Incentive a.OpenProject").on("click", this.enterProjectAnim)
    },
    enterProjectAnim: function () {
        var e = this;
        App.Router.navigate("/case-projet/Incentive", {trigger: true})
        , $("#homepage").css("display", "none")
        , e.caseStudyElem.css({ display: "block" })
        , $("#partech-introduction").addClass("active")
    }
});

})();
```

In Chrome Dev Tools:

Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); } has no method 'navigate'

i tried with the response of [Backbone Router has no method navigate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612087/backbone-router-has-no-method-navigate) but this does not work.

Why have i this error ?

Tks :)

Comment: Looks similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612087/backbone-router-has-no-method-navigate

Comment: I know but this does not work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the call `App.Router.navigate(...)` to `Backbone.history.navigate(...)`.

Alternatively, you could set a variable to the `new App.Router()` instance you create, and then call the `navigate` function on that instance. Your code is trying to call the `navigate` on the class definition; you need an instance of the class instead.

Comment: Tks ! it is Good ! For you, the best practice is which ?

Comment: Great, glad to hear it. I use `Backbone.history.navigate` myself, and I see it in a lot of other code, too. It's available everywhere in my application via the `Backbone` global, so I don't have to make my own Router instance available from other modules.